# useNavigate() is having routing issues

Tags: reactjs

below is the error message; the route is like this: loging -> countryselection -> dashboard. i have created buttons which should direct me to the dashboard page. but when i click them, it rarely take me to dashboard. and i got these errors. please help, thanks. i have also tried enclosed the button within the  to direct the page, and i also got the same error.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
react-dom.development.js:18655 The above error occurred in the <Route.Provider> component:

    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:109822:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:109755:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:108564:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18655
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18688
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13980
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:14003
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23222
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24500
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24486
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24424
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26631
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26499
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25931
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12103
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25468
react-dom.development.js:19012 Uncaught Error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.
    at throwException (react-dom.development.js:19012)
    at handleError (react-dom.development.js:26129)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26259)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25664)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25910)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12103)
    at react-dom.development.js:25468
```

```
import { Typography } from 'antd'
import './countryselection.scss'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { db } from '../../Utils/firebase-connection'
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const { Title } = Typography
function CountrySelection() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const changeCountry = () => {
    // localStorage.setItem('country', name)
     navigate('/dashboard')
  };
  function UserButton(name) {
    return (
    <div className='container padded' key={name}>
                <button onClick={ () => changeCountry() } className='button'>{ name }</button>
        </div>
    )
  }

  const user3 = ''
  console.log('userinfo', user3);
  // const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
  console.log('user', user3)
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  function getCountries() {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'users', user3);
    getDoc(docRef)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            const tempCountries = response.data().countries.map(doc => ({
              label: doc,
            }))
            console.log('countries', tempCountries)
            if (tempCountries.length === 1) {
              // navigate('/dashboard')
            }
            setCountries(tempCountries);
            // country = tempCountries;
            console.log('result', tempCountries);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="country-wrapper">
      <div className='country-form'>
        <div>
        <Title
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            margin: '1rem 0 1rem 0',
            color: 'white',
          }}
          level={3}
        >
          Select a Country
        </Title>
        </div>
        {countries.map((e) => UserButton(e.label))}
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CountrySelection
```